# Error when add GlassFish 3 in netbean 7.3

Tags: web-applications, netbeans, glassfish

I installed NetBeans 7.3 and didn't install GlassFish server. After that, I downloaded separately GlassFish server 3.x.x.zip and unzip.

But when I add GlassFish server to Netbeans, then create New Project **Web Application** of **Java Web**, in step 3 "**Sever and Setting**"     NetBeans informs me that:

"**No servers are registered in the IDE. To register a server, click the "Add..." button.**" .

Despite I installed Tomcat. However, I remove glassFish server, and create  New Project **Web Application** again, everything happen normal.

I don't know why, and How I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

when you install netbeans, a default server is installed with it, but server's version depends on netbeans's version which you installed. Sometime we need a different version of server and no need of the default server so we installed it separately like you did.

Now you can solve this problem 
go to you project, right click on it, go to properties, click on run, then select which server you want to select as a default server so that when you build your app then this server will use as a default server.